# Which came first, the "S" or the Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, names

Disclaimer: I have **not** read many Superman Comics.

---

In the Superman Movies and in the TV Show Smallville, Superman's iconic S was used as The El family crest.

Was this original intention?

I originally thought that the name "Superman" garnered the S.

Then if you listen to the old Superman radio show, it was a boy who gave him the name "Superman" based off of the S he was wearing.

So this ends up as big "chicken in the egg" question:
**Which came first, the "S" or the Superman?**

Comment: w00h00!! I was just thinking about this a few weeks ago actually. Not so much the "S" or "Superman" thing, but specifically the movie where the only "coat of Arms" that wasn't some random design was the \S/. Thanks for asking!

Comment: [**S**iegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Siegel) and [**S**huster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Shuster).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the Wikipedia on [Superman logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_logo):

> Initially, the S-shield had one meaning: **S for Superman**. One of the first alternative meanings was presented in Superman: The Movie, in which it was not an S, but rather the **S-shaped Coat of arms of the House of El**. After the Superman reboot story The Man of Steel, the symbol's story was that it was designed by Jonathan Kent and was **derived from an ancient Native American symbol**. The symbol was featured on a medicine blanket given to an ancestor of the Kent family by a Native American tribe after he helped to cure them of a plague and was supposed to represent a snake, an animal held to possess healing powers by the tribe (implying that, by wearing this symbol, Superman was a metaphorical healer). In 2004, Mark Waid's Superman: Birthright series says the S-Shield is the **Kryptonian symbol for "hope"** **and** Superman believes it may have begun as a **coat of arms for the House of El**. Later, writer Geoff Johns **confirmed it was indeed a coat of arms, as well as a symbol for hope.**

Comment: Wow, they really tried hard to make it mean more then just a letter of the alphabet.